# How do we render tweet button on ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp

Following is the code to tweet from my website

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"  data-lang="en" data-url="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$share; ?>" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

I am doing `ajax` pagination on page in `CAKEPHP`, but tweet button works fine one page:1 but on `ajax` call to 2nd, 3rd page etc  tweet option left with tweet text and link. it's not rendering the widget.js?
can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you really need to re-render the Twitter button on every new page?

Comment: Borislav-- Yes i was re-rendering Actually i was doing pagination via ajax, when i moved to page:2, rendering issue was coming up. anyways i solved it. thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Its done, we just need to render the tweet css and java-script after ajax call. Very simple and small solution to use twttr.widgets.load(); into the DOM. Thanx

Comment: you save my time, that small solution change my big problem on my web page. it;s worked and i implement it on my web http://kompetisiindonesia.com/kompetisi/detail/TlRVMw/lomba-logo-hut-ke-59-pertamina

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you render your own tweet button, just calling twitter.com/share?url=… You can get the current url in javascript with location.href (must be url encoded after).

Comment: superrache -- thanx its done, i just used twittr.widget.load() into the DOM. it reloads the tweet after every ajax call.